Video.js Update Handling Issue with Dynamic MPD (TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined)
Description:
I'm encountering a playback issue with Video.js when using a dynamic (Live) MPD DASH manifest for a live video stream. The video stream is an MP4 file segmented according to DASH standards and plays the initial segments correctly. However, Video.js seems to have difficulty handling subsequent updates to the MPD, resulting in the error:
VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined
  at video.js:42423:19
  at video.js:40328:11
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at forEachMediaGroup (video.js:40321:28)
  at removeOldMediaGroupLabels (video.js:42422:5)
  at updateMain (video.js:42483:5)
  at DashPlaylistLoader.handleMain_ (video.js:42939:19)
  at DashPlaylistLoader.refreshMedia_ (video.js:43034:14)
  at DashPlaylistLoader.<anonymous> (video.js:42565:14)
  at data.dispatcher (video.js:2206:33)

code I use:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Video.js Player</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <!--<style>
      /* Your CSS styles */
  </style>-->
</head>
<video id ="vid1" class="video-js" controls width="640" height="320" poster="VideoPoster.jpg" id=vid1 class="vjs-default-skin">
  <source src="https://localhost:7249/GenerateMPD/DownloadMPD/video_segmented_dash.mp4" type="application/dash+xml">
</video>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-dash/dist/videojs-dash.cjs.js"></script> -->

<script>
  var player = videojs('vid1', {
      controls: true,
      autoplay: true,
      preload: 'auto',
      playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 4, 8, 16],
      liveui: true


  });
  player.play();
  


</script>

</html>


The API returns an MPD file for a "dynamic" dash manifest:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd" type="dynamic" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT5.000S" minBufferTime="PT2S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT10M17.196S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M5.000S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT30M" availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" publishTime="2024-04-16T13:08:35Z" suggestedPresentationDelay="PT10M17.196S">
    <Period id="0">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="15" sar="1:1" bandwidth="264151">
                <BaseURL>http://localhost:3000/video/video_segmented_dash</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="90000" duration="191989">
                    <Initialization range="0-830"/>
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="831-79757" indexRange="831-882"/>
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="79758-153575" indexRange="79758-79809"/>
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="153576-235715" indexRange="153576-153627"/>
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="235716-316868" indexRange="235716-235767"/>
<!-- more -->
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>

Context:

Live Stream Setup: Live video stream from an MP4 file segmented on the fly.

Video stream is video-only (no audio).

**MPD Configuration: **The MPD is dynamic with minimumUpdatePeriod="PT5.000S" (updates every 5 seconds).

MPD uses SegmentURL and indexRange for segment information.

Playback Behavior: The initial segments from the first MPD are played correctly.

Video.js fails to recognize updates to the MPD and throws the error, preventing playback of new segments.


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the initial MPD and video segments are playable. the mpd is DASH-
IF Conformant.

Confirmed the API is updating the MPD dynamically with the expected update period specified by  minimumUpdatePeriod .


Questions:

How can I ensure Video.js properly handles updates to the dynamic MPD and refreshes the segments accordingly? Are there specific methods or events within Video.js that can be leveraged for this purpose?

Are there any known compatibility issues with Video.js and dynamic MPD updates?

Could there be any potential issues with the way the updated MPD is being generated by the server-side logic?


